# How can I tackle this integral $\int_2^3 {\rm}\frac{1}{x([\ln(x))]^5} \, dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration

I admit to having challenges this calculus and integral how do i solve this? I have not tried anything because it is just difficult and i need to do more practice I will not give up. bare with me please.
$$
  \int_2^3 \frac{1}{x(\ln(x))^5}\;\mathrm{d}x
$$
step by step how can i solve this?

Comment: Try $u=\ln(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not worry do more practice as you said :
This is how I would approach it;

let $u =\ln x$ and $du = \frac{dx}{x}$

So:
$$
\int_2^3 {\rm}\frac{dx}{x(\ln x)^5} = \int_{\ln 2}^{\ln 3} {\rm}\frac{du}{u^5} 
= \int_{\ln 2}^{\ln 3}{\rm}u^{-5}du  
= \frac{-1}{4} \frac{1}{u^4}
$$
and your answer is
$$\frac{-1}{4} \, \left( \frac{1}{(\ln3)^4}- \frac{1}{(\ln2)^4} \right)$$

Comment: let me do it and with your answer see if i will get the same. Thank you

Comment: welcome and goodluck

Answer (score 2):

Instead of just using the substitution as otherwise suggested, some intuition into why you should is that we can rewrite our integral as $$\int_{2}^{3} (\log x)^{-5} \cdot \dfrac{1}{x} \text{ d}x$$ which is of the form $$ \int_{a}^{b} \left[ f(x) \right]^n f'(x) \text{ d}x = \dfrac{ \left[ f(x) \right]^{n+1} }{n+1} \ \Bigg|_{a}^{b} $$ by noticing that this is kinda like reversing the chain rule.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: $u = \ln x$, then $du = \dfrac{1}{x}dx$. Thus: $I = \displaystyle \int_{\ln 2}^{\ln 3} u^{-5}du=....$

Comment: let me use this to simplify and see if i will get the below answer